# I want to make new blocks appear with javascript

Tags: javascript

I write with translate.

I want to make new blocks appear with javascript, and I need help, I'm just a beginner and I don't know if I'm doing everything right.

1. I made a block - div 30%, a paragraph and a button.

[image]

2. After pressing the button another block appears - div 30%, with the same paragraph and add another input as well as copy the button from the last block div (1).

[image]

3. Now I want the last 30% div block to appear with the text of the previous block and the number that I will write randomly after I click on the next button.

[image]

- How can I realize my problem, or how can I start and end correctly, I may not do correctly, but I don't know how to prolong it the same way,

my variant, code HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <p>test</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">ok</button>
    </div>
    <div id="demo"></div>  
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.col-sm{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

JS code:

```
 function myFunction(){ 
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =   

    '<div class="col-sm">'+
        '<p>test</p>'+
        '<input type="" name="">'+
        '<button>ok</button>'+
    '</div>'; 
}
```

Obviously I am not doing something right, but as I said I have just started to learn and I have no other options on how to solve this problem, I will be grateful for any advice or help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting and powerful when you can "create" html code by adding it with javascript, but while learning more I'd suggest you to also have a look on how to show/hide elements with CSS (a good start is `display: none;`) so that you can already type in your HTML file all the elements you want, but hide some of them.
Once it's time to show your elements, just change their style to get rid of the `display: none;` or use a CSS class to do so (a class that hides the element, that you remove when you want to show it).

Here's an example by using your code as source:

```js
 function myFunction(){ 
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =   

    '<div class="col-sm">'+
        '<p>test</p>'+
        '<input type="number" name="" id="myValue">'+
        '<button onclick="myOtherFunction()">ok</button>'+
    '</div>'; 
}

 function myOtherFunction(){ 
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML =   

    '<div class="col-sm">'+
        '<p>test</p>'+
        document.getElementById('myValue').value+
    '</div>'; 
}
```

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.col-sm{
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
        <p>test</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">ok</button>
    </div>
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <div id="answer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and suggestions. I will draw attention to what is written above, thank you.